# do bitwise and operation with a given value which results in a desired output

Tags: c++, c, bitwise-and

I want to determine the value of X in the below mentioned operations:

```
X & 0x08 = 8
```

How to find out x in this scenario?

Comment: There is no number X such that `X & 8 == 124`. 8 has only 1 bit lit in binary representation, so anything bitwise AND 8 will be 8 or 0.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen this is just an example let say the expected value is 8 then how can i find it? Is there a formula for a way to determine the value of X.

Comment: You can't. This is like saying "what numbers have 2 in the second digit?" It's a lot of them.

Comment: If you're asking about this in a more generalized sense, maybe you need to read up on [SAT solvers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem).

Comment: The bitwise AND operation is preserving only the bits corresponding to `1` in the mask. The others are lost forever and not recoverable.

Comment: not every operation can be inverted unambiguously. Whats the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there are many numbers that combined with given number would give you the same result. Bitwise operations are not really reversible like arithmetic operations.
You can however find a set of possible numbers X that would produce the correct result. The algorithm for that would be quite simple (and language agnostic).

Let's say we want `X & b == c`, where `b` is 12 and `c` is 8. You need to get binary representations of both the known number and the result

```
b == 12 == 00001100
c ==  8 == 00001000
```

The rules that X must meet are the following:

- For every bit equal to 1 in `c`, corresponding bits in `b` and `X` must be equal to 1
- For bit equal to 0 in `c`, if corresponding bit in `b` is 1 then corresponding bit in `X` must be 0.
- For bit equal to 0 in `c`, if corresponding bit in `b` is 0 then value of corresponding bit in `X` is unknown.

By these rules, we can determine that in our example

```
b == 12 == 00001100
c ==  8 == 00001000
X       == ????10??
```

Under every `?` you can substitute either 1 or 0 and you will get a correct result. For example, both `00001000` (8) and `11111011` (251) will be a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking this, then there can be several things you don't understand.

```
X & 0x08 = 8
```

Let's start with the easiest part: 0x08. This is just the hexadecimal representation, which is how computer programmers think when they want to know what the individual bytes hold. (If you don't know what a byte is, do a Google for `computer memory byte`. This is a VERY important concept.)

In this case, 0x08 is just a normal 8. In binary, that means 0000 1000. Exactly one bit is set.

Now let's do the & sign. In this case, it stands for bitwise-AND. (If you don't know what a bit is, continue reading about bits and bytes. A bit is a single binary digit in a byte. A 0 or 1.)

There are a few basic bit operations.

```
& -- AND -- the corresponding bit in both numbers is set
| -- OR  -- if either is set
^ -- XOR -- exclusive or -- one or the other is set
```

So if we have two numbers, A and B as follows:

```
A 0101 0101
B 0000 1111
```

Then:
A & B == 0000 0101
A | B == 0101 1111
A ^ B == 0101 1010

So... in the case of X & 0x08, that 0x08 == 0000 1000. You should be able to figure it out from here.